# Changing a variable inside a struct, inside a map-key, from another cpp file

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

I'm new to C++, so I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way, but my question is:

How can I access and change a variable that is defined inside a struct, which is inside a map, from another .cpp file?

#### Part of my .h file:

```
struct Borough {
    std::string name = "";
    int num_players = 0;
    Borough(std::string n) : name(n) {}
    friend inline bool operator< (const Borough& lhs, const Borough& rhs){ return (lhs.name < rhs.name); }
    friend inline bool operator==(const Borough& lhs, const Borough& rhs){ return (lhs.name == rhs.name); }
};

class Graph {
public:
    typedef std::map<Borough, Vertex *> vmap;
    vmap walk;
};
```

#### And (part of) the player.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include "player.h"

void Player::move() {
    std::string current_loc = get_location();
    std::cout << "\nWhere do you want to move to?" << std::endl;
    display_branches(current_loc);

    std::string selected_location;
    std::getline(std::cin, selected_location);

    // verification and placement of player:
    if (verify_location(current_loc, selected_location)) {
        set_location(selected_location);
        // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO MAKE Borough::num_players++;
        std::cout << m_graph.walk.find(selected_location)->first.num_players << " <-- That's the number of players.\n";
    }
}
```

I know I can *display* the number, but I want to change it by incrementing by +1 when a player successfully "moves" there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map`'s key_type is always `const`, because it would be an error to modify the key in such a way that it might change its proper location within the map (tree).

But the only part that matters is the part which affects the location in the map.  `std::map` has no way to know this, but in your case, a Borough's comparison only involves its `name` and not `num_players`.

The easiest way to fix this is to mark `num_players` as `mutable`:

```
mutable int num_players = 0;
```

Then you'll be able to modify this value even in a `const Borough`.  It won't harm anything, so long as your Borough comparators do not depend on `num_players`.